# Program not executing function when mouse is clicked

Tags: java, swing, mouse, awt, mouseclick-event

When the mouse is left-clicked, the colors horizontally adjacent to each other are supposed to swap and when right-clicked, the colors vertically adjacent are supposed to swap. Nothing is happening when I click either button.

code in question:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import sun.java2d.loops.DrawRect;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
//instance variables
private int width;
private int height;
private Block topLeft;
private Block topRight;
private Block botLeft;
private Block botRight;

public Board()  //constructor
{
    width = 200;
    height = 200;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}

//initialization constructor
 public Board(int w, int h)  //constructor
 {
    width = w;
    height = h;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}



public void update(Graphics window)
{
    paint(window);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics window)
 {
super.paintComponent(window);
topRight.draw(window);
topLeft.draw(window);
botRight.draw(window);
botLeft.draw(window);


}

 public void swapTopRowColors()
{
Color temp = topLeft.getColor();
topLeft.setColor(topRight.getColor());
topRight.setColor(temp);
repaint();
}

public void swapBottomRowColors()
{
   Color temp = botLeft.getColor();
   botLeft.setColor(botRight.getColor());
   botRight.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
}

public void swapLeftColumnColors()
{
   Color temp = botLeft.getColor();
   botLeft.setColor(topLeft.getColor());
   topLeft.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
}

public void swapRightColumnColors()
{
   Color temp = botRight.getColor();
   botRight.setColor(topRight.getColor());
   topRight.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    int mouseX=e.getX();
    int mouseY=e.getY();
    int mouseButton = e.getButton();

    if(mouseButton==MouseEvent.BUTTON1)     //left mouse button pressed
    {
        if(mouseX>=topLeft.getX() && mouseX<=topLeft.getWidth() && mouseY>=topLeft.getY() && mouseY<=topLeft.getY())
        {
            this.swapTopRowColors();
        }

        else if(mouseX>=topRight.getX() && mouseX<=topRight.getWidth() && mouseY>=topRight.getY() && mouseY<=topRight.getY())
        {
            this.swapTopRowColors();
        }

        else if(mouseX>=botLeft.getX() && mouseX<=botLeft.getWidth() && mouseY>=botLeft.getY() && mouseY<=botLeft.getY())
        {
            this.swapBottomRowColors();
        }

        else if(mouseX>=botRight.getX() && mouseX<=botRight.getWidth() && mouseY>=botRight.getY() && mouseY<=botRight.getY())
        {
            this.swapBottomRowColors();
        }

    }
    //right mouse button pressed
    if(mouseX>=topLeft.getX() && mouseX<=topLeft.getWidth() && mouseY>=topLeft.getY() && mouseY<=topLeft.getY())
    {
        this.swapLeftColumnColors();
    }

    else if(mouseX>=topRight.getX() && mouseX<=topRight.getWidth() && mouseY>=topRight.getY() && mouseY<=topRight.getY())
    {
        this.swapRightColumnColors();
    }

    else if(mouseX>=botLeft.getX() && mouseX<=botLeft.getWidth() && mouseY>=botLeft.getY() && mouseY<=botLeft.getY())
    {
        this.swapLeftColumnColors();
    }

    else if(mouseX>=botRight.getX() && mouseX<=botRight.getWidth() && mouseY>=botRight.getY() &&    mouseY<=botRight.getY())
    {
        this.swapRightColumnColors();
    }









}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

//toString
}
```

and the code that starts it:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BlockGame extends JFrame
{
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;

public BlockGame()
{
    super("Board");
    setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    getContentPane().add(new Board(500,500));

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    BlockGame run = new BlockGame();

}
}
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger and check that you are actually getting into the if-statements? Maybe the mouse isn't being clicked where you think. You can use print statements to print the coordinates.

Comment: what attempts have you made yourself to debug it?

Comment: I did write the code and have never debugged using a debugger and thus, I have no idea on how to use it to narrow down to a problem in the code.... I just haven't had formal instruction on debugging using a debugger or to this degree

Comment: @tech_geek23, then you can use print statements.  Put `System.out.println("X: " + mouseX + " Y: " + mouseY);` to make sure you are getting coordinates you expect. Also, make sure the values you are getting back from Block are correct.  Since we can't see the Block class we can't tell if it is doing something that might cause it to return a different value.

Comment: ok, took your suggestion and it looks to be that the mouse is clicking at the appropriate coordinates but the action is just not executing

Comment: Block class: http://pastebin.com/dYFj4aYg

Comment: @tech_geek23, did you check that `topLeft` is returning correct coordinates? What do you mean by "action is just not executing".  Is it not calling the function `swapTopRowColors()` is being called? I would put print statements there, too.  The basics of debugging is putting print statements everywhere to actually see what your program is doing.  If you can't debug your program then we can't help you.

Comment: the colors are not swapping as they should which seems that it would be due to the `swap*****Colors()` not getting called some how in the if/else statements for the mouse clicks

Comment: @tech_geek23, right, so if it isn't being called that means the if-statement isn't resolving to true. The only way to find out *why* is to put up print statements and see what all the values are of the if-statement.

Comment: here's what my samples were when I used your suggestion to find out if it knew the mouse was being clicked: `X: 410 Y: 339
X: 413 Y: 116
X: 208 Y: 108
X: 106 Y: 402
X: 83 Y: 474
X: 76 Y: 500
X: 2 Y: 381
X: 122 Y: 354
X: 31 Y: 25
X: 310 Y: 73
X: 317 Y: 153
X: 355 Y: 329
X: 355 Y: 329
X: 380 Y: 367
`

so by all means, these values should execute the color swaps

Comment: *"why the down vote?"*  Good question.  +1 for a ..good question.

Comment: my thought now is that it could have to do with the MouseEvent methods at the very bottom.... any help on those? I haven't dealt much with MouseEvent methods

Comment: here is something I found when checking back over my debugger: `public Board(int w, int h)  //constructor` eclipse had it highlighted in green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final code ended up like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//import sun.java2d.loops.DrawRect;

import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class Board extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
//instance variables
private int width;
private int height;
private Block topLeft;
private Block topRight;
private Block botLeft;
private Block botRight;

public Board()  //constructor
{
    width = 200;
    height = 200;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}

  //initialization constructor
public Board(int w, int h)  //constructor
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    topLeft=new Block(0,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.RED);
    topRight=new Block(width/2,0,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.GREEN);
    botLeft=new Block(0,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.BLUE);
    botRight=new Block(width/2,height/2,width/2-10,height/2-10,Color.YELLOW);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    //start trapping for mouse clicks
    addMouseListener(this);
}



public void update(Graphics window)
{
    paint(window);
}

 public void paintComponent(Graphics window)
 {
super.paintComponent(window);
topRight.draw(window);
topLeft.draw(window);
botRight.draw(window);
botLeft.draw(window);


}

  public void swapTopRowColors()
 {
Color temp = topLeft.getColor();
Color temp2 = topRight.getColor();
topRight.setColor(temp);
topLeft.setColor(temp2);

repaint();
}

public void swapBottomRowColors()
{
   Color temp = botLeft.getColor();
   Color temp2 = botRight.getColor();
   botLeft.setColor(temp2);
   botRight.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
 }

public void swapLeftColumnColors()
{
   Color temp = botLeft.getColor();
   Color temp2 = topLeft.getColor();
   botLeft.setColor(temp2);
   topLeft.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
}

public void swapRightColumnColors()
 {
   Color temp = botRight.getColor();
   Color temp2 = topRight.getColor();
   botRight.setColor(temp2);
   topRight.setColor(temp);
   repaint();
 }

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    int mouseX=e.getX();
    int mouseY=e.getY();
    int mouseButton = e.getButton();
    //System.out.println("User clicked at " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
    if(mouseButton == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)       //left mouse button pressed
    {
        if(((mouseX>= 0 && mouseX <= topLeft.getWidth()-1) && (mouseY>= 0 && mouseY <= (topLeft.getHeight()-1))) || ((mouseX>= topRight.getX() && mouseX <= (topRight.getX()+topRight.getWidth())-1) && (mouseY>= 0 && mouseY <= (topRight.getY()+topRight.getHeight()-1))))
        {
            this.swapTopRowColors();
        }
        else
        {
            this.swapBottomRowColors();
        }





    }
    //right mouse button pressed
    else
    {
        if(((mouseX>= 0 && mouseX <= topLeft.getWidth()-1) && (mouseY>=0 && mouseY <=  (topLeft.getHeight()-1))) || ((mouseX>= botLeft.getX() && mouseX <= (botLeft.getX()+botLeft.getWidth())-1) && (mouseY>= 0 && mouseY <= (botLeft.getY()+(botLeft.getHeight()-1)))))
    {
        this.swapLeftColumnColors();
    }
        else
        {
            this.swapRightColumnColors();
        }




    }





    System.out.println(botLeft.getHeight() + ", " + botLeft.getY());




}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }

 //toString
}
```

and it works very well. Had one color issue that came from a copy/paste error I didn't catch but is fixed.

Comment: Actually, I think you've reached a edge case that just "happens" to work

Comment: If you change the position of your squares, then you check has the potential to fail, rather then actually checking that the point falls within a given rectangle, your making assumptions about there positions, the first been the y position - IMHO

Answer (score 5):

You have two issues...

```
mouseX >= topLeft.getX() && mouseX <= topLeft.getWidth()
```

This is checking to see if the mouse position is greater or equal to the blocks x position (this is good) and less then or equal to it's width....??? So if I had a box that was at 100 with a width of 10 and I clicked at 105, then this check would fail.

```
105 >= 100 && 105 < 10 // .... ???
```

And then there's this...

```
mouseY >= topLeft.getY() && mouseY <= topLeft.getY()
```

Take a moment to check the last condition...You'd have to click EXACTLY on the top edge of the block for this condition to be true.

I would do one of two things.

Either I would write a method that performs this calculation for any block...

```
public boolean contains(Point p, Block block) {
    return p.x >= block.getX() && p.x <= block.getX() + block.getWidth() && 
            p.y >= block.getY() && p.y <= block.getY() + block.getHeight();
}
```

That way, if there is ever a bug in the code, it's only in one place...

OR (preferrably), I would extended the `Block` from [`Rectangle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), this way I could simply use the `contains` method instead...

```
public class Block extends Rectangle {

    private Color color;

    public Block(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(this);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

And in your mouse clicked event handler...

```
if (topLeft.contains(e.getPoint()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think you're confusing screen with window coordinates here: getX() returns mouse coordinates **relative to the source compontent**, which might not be what you want in this particular case ...
- Print out a line to check whether or not the program actually reaches the mouseClicked() function. Might want to bind it to mousePressed(), and see if it registers then.
- You've got 4 if statements (if, else if, else if, else if), but no final statement for when those 4 fail, allowing the program to silently fall through all of those options. You obviously don't expect any other option, but that's probably what happens - print out a line there with some debug output (X,Y, source component), and you probably will learn a lot. :)

Comment: when checking over the debugger again, I did find this: `public Board(int w, int h)  //constructor` eclipse highlighted it in green

Comment: also, I don't think it's getting screen coordinates as when I clicked anywhere else, it didn't print out those values

Comment: Myes, but that's not really telling us much ... just looks like the definition of your Board class' constructor.

Put a breakpoint in your mouseClicked() function, then run your program in debug mode, to see if the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: when I breakpoint-ed the `mouseClicked()` function, it hit it, continued and then said to debug `int mouseX=e.getX();`

Comment: Yes, and now you're stepping over it, you can actually see what these functions return ... do you enter one of your if-tests? I guess not.

Just adding `system.out.println("User clicked at " + e.getX() + "," + e.getY())` would get you far.

Comment: got this: `User clicked at 428,192
X: 428 Y: 192`

Comment: good news, it is working for 3 of the 4 squares... top left is not working for vertical or horizontal. but this could be if it's just resulting to it as default